# Send Firebase FCM token to the backend in symfony

Tags: php, firebase, symfony, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on symfony website and want to push notifications through firebase

```
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login';
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('Token sent successfully.');
    } else {
        console.error('Error sending token:', xhr.statusText);
    }
};
console.log('Device token:', currentToken);
console.log('Token generated successfully.');

// send the token to the backend

xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error('Error sending token:', xhr.statusText);
};
console.log(JSON.stringify({token: currentToken}));
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({token: currentToken}));
```

In above code I am able to successfully generated the token, now I want to send this to backend server.

I am using symfony controller method for backend handling.

This is the method in which i want to send the token from front end:

```
 /**
 *  @Route("/login", name="app_login", methods={"POST", "GET"})
 * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
 * @return Response
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request): Response
{

    $content = $request->getContent();
    $jsonData = json_decode($content);

    if (!$jsonData || !isset($jsonData->token)) {
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Invalid request.'], 400);
    }

    $token = $jsonData->token;
    dd($token);


    if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_role');
    }
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
   
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();


    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'testimonials' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Testimonial::class)->findAll(),
        'error' => $error,
    
    ]);
}
```

I am unable to get the token in the login method.

Comment: Could you make a "dump($request->getContent())"? Do you have the payload inside?